# cursive character segmentation in OCR

Tags: opencv, visual-c++, image-segmentation

I have done a `OCR application` for `handwritten normal characters`.For the segmentation of characters I have used `histogram profile method`. That successfully works for normal English characters.

I have used horizontal projection for line segmentation and vertical projection for character segmentation.

To segment lines of cursive hand written article I can use horizontal projection as previous. But I can't use same methodology for cursive English character segmentation since they are merged each other and also slanted. Can anyone please help me with a way to segment cursive characters.

Comment: I can vaguely remember this.. how about if you rotate the letters so they are upright, and the baseline is diagonal?

Comment: approximatively segment one then recognize it, if it is not recognized try to tune its segmentation, and so one.

Answer (score 3):

This is a difficult problem to solve due to the variability between writers and character shapes. One option, which has achieved up to 83% accuracy, is to analyze the ligatures (connections between characters) in the writing and draw columns on the image using those ligatures as a base point. In 2013, Procedia Computer Science proposed this approach and published their research on this particular problem: https://ac.els-cdn.com/S1877050913001464/1-s2.0-S1877050913001464-main.pdf?_tid=5f55eac2-0077-11e8-9d79-00000aacb35f&acdnat=1516737513_c5b6e8cb8184f69b2d10f84cd4975d56

Another approach to try is called skeletal analysis which takes the word as a whole and matches its shape with other known word shapes and predicts the word based on the entire image.

Good luck!